# Is it possible to get a release pipeline creation date on Azure Devops/TFS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I was wondering if it is possible to find the exact creation date as a predefined variable for a Release in Azure Devops. In release pipelines it can be seen as an actual column labeled "Created" (along with "Releases" and "Stages" to the left and right of "Created" respectively) - so I know that the data is stored somewhere.

The only variable I have been able to find is Release.Deployment.StartTime - which is the time the release deployment begins, which can be hours or even days after Release Creation, so not quite what I want.

Is there a way to do this? I attached a screenshot to show what I am trying to get.

[image]

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

What about `$(SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME)` ?

I like this task which dumps all the variables for you. I have it at the start of all my dev pipelines: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.DisplayAllVariables

You can also do it with powershell if you don't have access to install extensions:

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

If none of the variable work you can also publish your own variable with a Powershell task. It will be about 5-10 seconds later than the real stage execution time:

```
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DateTime;]$DateTime"
```

Answer (score 0):

You always can run a rest api call to see release details. Here is the example of a stage step with powershell:

```
$user = ""
$token = "$(System.AccessToken)"
$teamProject = "$(System.TeamProject)"
$releaseId = "$(Release.ReleaseId)"
$orgUrl = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
$orgUrlrel = $orgUrl -replace "dev", "vsrm.dev" 

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uriGetRelease = "$orgUrlrel/$teamProject/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId"+"?api-version=5.1"

$resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetRelease -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "Created date:" $resultStatus.createdOn
```

Additionally, you have to enable access to the token:

[image]